# WordPress and Localization

Tags: multi-language, localization

I know that WordPress supports multiple languages - You can read more details here http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language

My question is, what is the difference in a localized version over the standard english versoin? Does it only contain extra language files? What should I look for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The localized version is the English version translated. It contains the original and translated strings. You should look for missing translations or badly translated strings.

Use a desktop tool like [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) or a plugin like [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codestyling-localization/) to manage your WordPress, Themes and Plugins translations (the localized `.po` and `.mo` files).

Comment: So, other than the setup of wp_config.php of the local language, I should only care about the directories for the languages. That simple huh? Thanks.